# updateNumericInput not updating from reactiveValues

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I think I have run into some strange scoping issue that I have fought with for a week now without understanding what is going on.
I have also been unable to really make a small example that have the same problem but I hope the symptoms ring some bells. The real code is also available but the app is pretty complex.

Let me explain the players in the code.

1. A number of inputs in a `bsModal`, mainly `numericInput`.
2. An `observeEvent`, lets call it "the reader", fires when a file is read that contains cached results. It updates a `reactiveValues` object that contains the equivalent of all the inputs in a special S4 object.
3. Then we have an `observe`, lets call it "the object creator" that takes all the inputs and updates the  reactiveValues` object if any inputs are changed.
4. an `observeEvent`, lets call it "the input updater", that fires when the `reactiveValues` reactive is invalidated and should update all the inputs. This is done to allow other processes to change the inputs by changing the `reactiveValues` reactive (for example "the object creator"). The first functionality I need is simply that it updates the inputs when the cached results are read by the "the object creator".

So it should go:
"the reader" reads a file --> "the input updater" sees a new `reactiveValues` reactive and updates the inputs (--> the "the object creator" sees new inputs and re-writes the `reactiveValues` reactive but they should be what the "the reader" already set).

The issue I have is in the "the input updater". I cannot get it to update the input based on the `reactiveValues`.

The code looks like this:

```
observeEvent(settings$processing_local, {

    cat("\n\n\n")
    print("Modifying inputs")
    print(paste0("before ppm input is: ", input$local_ppm))
  
    set <- ppm(settings$processing_local) # THIS DOES NOT WORK
    print(paste0("setting: ", set)) # SHOWS CORRECT VALUE
    # set <- 1000 # THIS WORKS!
  
   updateNumericInput(session,"local_ppm",value = set)
   
   print(paste0("after ppm input is: ", input$local_ppm))
   
   cat("\n\n\n")
  
}, priority = 2)
```

When `set` is based on the `reactiveValues` `settings$processing_local` then the update doesn't happen. The crazy thing is that the output of `print` *does* show the right value AND if I hardcode a value to `set` then it also works.
The full code for [1](https://gitlab.com/R_packages/mscurate/-/blob/master/shiny_mscurate/ui/settings_local_modal.R), [2](https://gitlab.com/R_packages/mscurate/-/blob/master/shiny_mscurate/server/load_from_cache.R#L32), [3](https://gitlab.com/R_packages/mscurate/-/blob/master/shiny_mscurate/server/settings_logic.R#L36) and [4](https://gitlab.com/R_packages/mscurate/-/blob/master/shiny_mscurate/server/settings_logic.R#L163).

EDIT 1: Version of the relevant processes based on the example of @cuttlefish44
This is closer to my action app but unfortunately does not have the problem I am experiencing in the full app.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("inNumber", "Input number", 0),
    actionButton("but", "Update")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    settings <- reactiveValues(aaa = NULL)
    
    
    # proxy for reading cached file
    observeEvent(input$but, {
      settings$aaa <- 30
      
    })
    

    
    observe({
      settings$aaa <- input$inNumber
      
    }, priority = 1)
    
    
    
    observeEvent(settings$aaa, {
        set <- settings$aaa
        print(c(set, input$inNumber))
        
        updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber", value = set)
        print(c(set, input$inNumber))
        
    }, priority = 2)
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

EDIT 2: In lieu of a working example of the issue I have dockerized my app so it should be possible to see the issue albeit annoying to do. Dockerized app [here](https://gitlab.com/R_packages/mscurate/-/tree/master/shiny_mscurate).
Can be build with `docker build --tag mscurate .` and run with `docker run --publish 8000:3838 mscurate`.
After starting the app the issue can be seen by:

1. click "Load"
2. Select the one available file
3. click "local settings"
4. Now the "ppm" value in the loaded data is 500. But the input was never updated and the reactive is then changed back to the default value of 100.

The logging shows the sequence of events when loading the file:

```
-------Loading started-------
before the reactive is:
settings not present
after the reactive is:
500
-------Loading finished-------

-------Modifying inputs-------
before ppm input is: 100
setting: 500
after ppm input is: 100     <---- @cuttlefish44's answer explains why this is not updated
--------------

-------updating reactive objects-------
before ppm input is: 100    <---- this should have been updated to 500!
before the reactive object is: 500
after ppm input is: 100
after the reactive object is: 100
--------------

-------Modifying inputs-------
before ppm input is: 100
setting: 100
after ppm input is: 100
--------------

-------updating reactive objects-------
before ppm input is: 100
before the reactive object is: 100
after ppm input is: 100
after the reactive object is: 100
--------------

-------updating reactive objects-------
before ppm input is: 100
before the reactive object is: 100
after ppm input is: 100
after the reactive object is: 100
--------------
```

Comment: What does the `ppm` function return? Is it supposed to return a `numeric`? Is it returning something else?

Comment: Thanks. No, it is indeed returning a `numeric`. Verified all the ways I could think of with `str` and `dput`.

Comment: If you could reduce the app a litte bit, especially by removing the packages that use `rJava`, it would help a lot. I was never able to install that package correctly and therefore cannot run your App..

Comment: Sounds a bit like an infinite loop in the making, with the RVs updating inputs and subsequently inputs updating the RVs. Also: `updateNumericInput()` won't change the values in the `input` object right after it's run, so the updated values wouldn't show up in the last print statement in your snippet.

Comment: @SeGa I have tried (see EDIT 1). But doing so I have been unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Mikko Marttila, yes you are right the is some chance of that, but I would handle that later by checking if the value really changed or not. Yes I understand now that I cannot check the input right after an update. But it truly seems not to change in my case. See the debugging output at the end of EDIT 2.

Comment: I couldn't get the containerized app to work (clicking "Load" resulted in an "unknown input format" error in `readRDS()`), but based on the logs you posted and a closer look at the source, I had a thought that I've posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the [“object creator” has a reactive
dependency on the RVs](https://gitlab.com/R_packages/mscurate/-/blob/master/shiny_mscurate/server/settings_logic.R#L39), causing it to invalidate in the same cycle as the
“input updater” when the “reader” updates the RVs. Then the settings are overwritten by the old `input` values before the update from the "input updater" takes place in the next cycle.

My interpretation of a play-by-play walkthrough would look something like this:

1. Reader updates settings, invalidating object creator and input updater.
2. New evaluation cycle starts.
3. Input updater sends a message to update input from new settings, but the
   values in the input object have not changed yet.
4. Object creator updates settings based on old input, invalidating settings
   and consequently input updater and object creator itself.
5. Input updater sends another message to update input, this time based on the
   old settings that object creator just set.
6. Object creator updates settings again, still based on old input. Invalidaiton
   is not triggered because the value hasn't changed.
7. All outputs are ready, evaluation ends and session is at rest.
8. Update messages sent by input updater arrive; only the latter is noted, which
   changes the input to the old value.
9. Object creator runs and sets settings to old value. Again, invalidation of
   settings is not triggered because the value didn't change.
10. Evaluation ends again, this time with no pending input messages.

To fix this, remove the RV dependencies from the “object creator”, e.g. with
`isolate()`. I couldn’t get `req()` to work with `isolate()`,
but in this case you could just drop that altogether.

Here’s a minimal example with the problem. Removing the `req()` here fixes it:

```r
library(shiny)

lgr <- list(debug = function(...) cat(sprintf(...), "\n"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("file_number", "Number to \"read from file\"", 0, 10, 5),
  actionButton("read", "Read"),
  numericInput("number", "Input number to sync", 0)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  settings <- reactiveValues(number = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$read, {
    settings$number <- input$file_number
    lgr$debug("Loaded settings from \"file\".")
  }, label = "reader")
  
  observe({
    req(settings$number) # The dependency on settings
    settings$number <- input$number
    lgr$debug("Updated settings from input.")
  }, priority = 1, label = "object-creator")
  
  observeEvent(settings$number, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "number", value = settings$number)
    lgr$debug("Set input from settings: %d", settings$number)
  }, priority = 2, label = "input-updater")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And the log produced after clicking “read”:

```
Loaded settings from "file". 
Set input from settings: 5 
Updated settings from input. 
Set input from settings: 0 
Updated settings from input. 
Updated settings from input.
```

You can get a good look at the process with [**reactlog**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=reactlog):

```r
reactlog::reactlog_enable()
reactlogReset()
shinyApp(ui, server)
reactlogShow()
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes AND yes! Thank you so much. That was the hint I needed. So the problem was ironically the debug messages calling the RV and the `req` that was required because of them. At the end of the “object creator” I also had a call to a function that would write the new RV to a file causing the same issue. Putting `isolate` inside the function's calls to the RV didn't help but wrapping the function call with `isolate` did solve it. So it now seems everything is working and I can finally move forward after 2 weeks of frustration. I will study your explanation to better really understand.

Comment: @JanStanstrup glad to hear you got it working! These kinds of things can be really tricky to spot sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but as far as I see `input` is static in the event.
See below simple example.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    sliderInput("controller", "Controller", 0, 20, 10),
    numericInput("inNumber", "Input number", 0),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    settings <- reactiveValues(aaa = NULL)
    
    observe({
        settings$aaa <- input$controller + 3

    }, priority = 1)
    
    observeEvent(settings$aaa, {
        set <- settings$aaa
        print(c(input$controller, set, input$inNumber))
        
        updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber", value = set)
        print(c(input$controller, set, input$inNumber))
        
    }, priority = 2)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I change controller 10 (default) to 12.

```
# this is console output
[1] 10 13  0
[1] 10 13  0
[1] 12 15 13
[1] 12 15 13
```

and the UI screen shot shows `inNumber` is updated to 15.
But console output shows input isn't updated immediately.
(maybe the updated value is in somewhere of `session` but I don't know where)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this. I truly appreciate it. Based on your example I added an example in EDIT 1 that more closely mirrors what I am doing. The annoying thing is that it works! In my desperation I have dockerized my app (see EDIT 2) and there the issue is apparent. I of course understand that this would be time consuming to look at, so feel free to ignore if my debugging output is not enough to get some idea of what is going on.